# Passing a vector from a dataframe column, stored in a list, to a glm

Tags: r, list, dataframe, vector, glm

I am attempting to fit a Poisson regression model to a dataset in R, whereby I have vectors of different lengths stored in two lists as dataframe columns, as so:

```
test <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = rnorm(10))
test$c <- list(length = nrow(test))
test$d <- list(length = nrow(test))

for(i in 1:nrow(test)) {

  test$c[[i]] <- LETTERS[1:sample(10:11, 1)]
  test$d[[i]] <- LETTERS[1:sample(10:11, 1)]
}
```

I need to build a model to predict `a` from `b` and the vectors `c` and `d`. As it is not possible to pass lists to a glm, I tried unlisting `c` and `d` to feed them into the model, but this just ends up creating one long vector for both `c` and `d`, meaning I get this error:

```
m0.glm <- glm(a ~ b + unlist(c) + unlist(d), data = test)

Error in model.frame.default(formula = a ~ b + unlist(c) + unlist(d),  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'unlist(c)')
```

I feel like there will be a simple solution that I am missing to my problem, but I have not had to attempt to pass a list of vectors to a model before.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you aware that `length(nrow(<any tabular format data>))` is always equal to 1? You are taking `nrow` (a scalar) then the `length` of this value.

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do in the `for` loop? If it just to select 10 letters, why a loop at all? `test$c <- LETTERS[sample(10:11, 10, TRUE)]`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I was supposed to set them to ```list(length = nrow(test))```, I will edit the question. I did it in a loop as I want to assign 10 vectors of variable lengths 10 and 11 to columns ```c``` and ```d```. If you could suggest a more memory efficient way then that would be great also.

Comment: 1) `test$c <- vector("list", length = nrow(test))`. 2) After the loop, try: `test$c <- lapply(test$c, paste, collapse = ",")`. And the same for `test$d`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas 2) Creates a vector of length one, which unfortunately defeats the aim of what I am trying to achieve: ```str(test$c[[1]])
 chr "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K"```. I need each element of the vector to stay separate, so that a each letter has a numeric prediction value attached to it.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is to create a df out of lists, then:

```
test <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = rnorm(10))
test$c <- list(length(nrow(test)))
test$d <- list(length(nrow(test)))

for(i in 1:nrow(test)) {

  test$c[[i]] <- LETTERS[1:sample(10:11, 1)]
  test$d[[i]] <- LETTERS[1:sample(10:11, 1)]
}

# 
do.call(rbind, lapply(test$c, function(x) {
  res <- rep(NA, max(vapply(test$c, length, integer(1))))
  res[1:length(x)] <- x
  res
})) -> test_c_df


do.call(rbind, lapply(test$d, function(x) {
  res <- rep(NA, max(vapply(test$d, length, integer(1))))
  res[1:length(x)] <- x
  res
})) -> test_d_df

test_new <- cbind(test[c("a", "b")], test_c_df, test_d_df)
names(test_new) <- make.unique(names(test_new))

m0.glm <- glm(a ~ ., data = test_new) # data reasonable??
```

Comment: This format would be fine if my use case was as small an example as this, but I actually have over 2000 possible levels for my factor variable. What I need for each of these variables is a predictor value of ```cA, cB, cC``` etc. and ```dA, dB, dC``` and so on, which is why I was trying to pass in the ```c``` and ```d``` columns as vectors, otherwise I would have to have a few thousand boolean columns for ```cA-ZZ``` and ```dA-ZZ```, which would only be "turned on" for 22 of the columns. I am feeding sports team lineups to a model, for context, if that helps with a solution.